# How to display navigationItem.title in a TabBar-connected ViewController after NavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, tabbar, navigationbar

Sorry for the confusing title. My Setup is just as simple as following:

```
`Navigation Controller -> View Controller1 -> Tab Bar Controller -> View Controller2
                                                                 -> View Controller3`
```

There is a show-segue, triggered by a BarButtonItem in ViewController1, which points to the TabBarController. For View Controller 2&3 (connected to the Tab Bar Controller), i configured the title and added a BarButtonItem on the top right. That's all. When I run the App, the title an buttons of VC2&3 are not shown, even if I set the title in the .swift-Class directly: 
(`self.navigationItem.title = "title of ViewController2"`)

Instead the simulator shows me a header with only a '< back' button in VC2&3.

What I want is the '< back' button + my title and right BarButtonItem. Sorry for asking such a trivial question, but I just can't find a solution.

I'm using Swift 2.1, Xcode 7.1, OS X 10.11.1
Thank you!

[Storyboard-Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4abtF.png)

Comment: Could you please attach a picture of your `storyboard` file?

Comment: I updated my question with a screenshot. You see my titles (page1 & page2) and the buttons. In the simulator they don't appear, just a back-button on the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, i finally found the solution for my case. ViewController1 can send the title for the VC2&3 in the prepareForSegue-method like:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let vc = segue.destinationViewController.navigationItem.title = "new title"
}
```

Or the better solution: ViewController2 set up its own title.

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        navigationController?.visibleViewController?.navigationItem.title = "new title"
    }
}
```